# Implement zxing.net.mobile in PCL

Tags: xamarin.android, zxing

I have to do barcode scanning. I have added zxing.net.mobile in Portable Class Library. But when call the scan method I am getting the below error.

> System.NotSupportedException: Use the platform specific implementation instead!

and my code looks like below.

```
public void Scan()
{
    MobileBarcodeScanningOptions options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
    options.DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 2000;
    options.AutoRotate = false;
    var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();            
    scanner.ScanContinuously(options, HandleScanResult);
}
private void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
    string msg;
    if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))  // Success
    {
        msg = result.Text;

    }
    else  // Canceled
    {
        msg = "Scanning Canceled!";
    }
}
```

How to solve this issue. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the ZXing.Net.Mobile Nuget package to both your PCL and your Platform Specific projects otherwise you will get the exception you mentioned.

For more information on how Xamarin plugins are implemented, this [Post](https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-reusable-plugins-for-xamarin-forms/) from James Montemagno should help.

Answer (score -1):

You add the Android Support Library v4 for your project android ?

Take a look at [that](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile) for more information.